# For a divergence free smooth vector field $v : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, how to find the commutator form of the matrix $A=(\partial_i v_j)$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, matrices

The question is as in the title.

I know that a traceless matrix can be written as a commutator of two matrices.

Then, let $v : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a divergence-free smooth vector field. That is, $\nabla \cdot v=0$.

Then, the matrix $A(x)=\bigl[\partial_i v_j(x) \bigr]$ is smooth as a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $M_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ and tracelss for each $x$.

Then, what does any two matrices $B(x)$ and $C(x)$ that satisfy $A(x)=B(x)C(x)-C(x)B(x)$ look like?

This is quite new and original for me..Could anyone please help me?

Comment: This is an underdetermined problem and there will be many possible solutions (and I doubt there is any particularly "natural" or "canonical" solution).  But most of the standard proofs that a traceless matrix are expressible as a commutator will come with a construction which one can then plug in your specific matrix into.  (As just one example: /https://www.isibang.ac.in/~soumyashant/misc/A_conceptual_approach_towards_understanding_matrix_commutators.pdf , though there are many others.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to first carry out a unitary transformation $A(x)\mapsto U(x)A(x)U^\top(x)$, such that all diagonal elements are zero.$^\ast$
Then $A(x)=BC(x)-C(x)B$ with
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&3
\end{pmatrix},\;\;
C_{ij}(x)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}\;i=j\\
\frac{A_{ij}(x)}{B_{ii}-B_{jj}}&\text{if}\;\;i\neq j.
\end{cases}
$$

---

$^\ast$ This is always possible for a traceless $A$ ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/267192/87355)).

For a $3\times 3$ matrix the unitary has the two-parameter form
$$U(x)=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\alpha(x)&\sin\alpha(x)&0\\
-\sin\alpha(x)&\cos\alpha(x)&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\cos\beta(x)&\sin\beta(x)\\
0&-\sin\beta(x)&\cos\beta(x)
\end{pmatrix}
.$$
You can solve first for $\alpha(x)$,
$$(\partial_1 v_1) \cos ^2\alpha+(\partial_2v_2) \sin ^2\alpha+ (\partial_1v_2+\partial_2 v_1)\sin\alpha\cos\alpha=0,$$
and then for $\beta(x)$.